# Influence of heatmap on point data

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I´ve got a quite specific question and hope someone understand what I want.

I´ve got two datasets (point-shapes):

1. Camera traps which gained data of roe deer on forest meadows
2. Camera traps which gained data of lynx (each camera trap counts given lynx event)

What I did:
I loaded both point-shapes in QGIS. Both point-shapes are overlapping each other.
I created a heatmap based on lynx events
[image][image]

> blue rhombus symbolize camera traps on meadows;
> heatmap symbolize the redder the more lynx-events were counted

What I want:
I want values of the heatmap (perhaps the center, camera traps where many lynx were present has a value of 10 and camera traps which had no lynx present has a value of 0), so I can question the roe deer camera traps which lynx-value they have.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Which tool are you using in QGIS? Can you add a screenshot to verify.

Comment: Could you symbolize the camera locations where the size of the dot represents the # of animals seen - bigger is more, smaller is less, and if you did that for both camera trap layers, each would have a different colour?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I did the dot size which get bigger the more lynx events were counted, but the meadows-cameras has a different data table, where the value of lynx presence only should be added

Comment: @whyzar I now added the screenshots of the tool I used

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this map.  I *think* that you want to display some sort of spatial relationship between lynx and deer.  Am I correct? It also appears that the points for both layers represent camera locations (NOT animal locations), and each point contains a count of the lynx and deer photographed from that location. If I am correct, how do you model the areas not seen by the cameras? Also, did a lynx camera ever photograph a deer, and vice versa? Perhaps you could edit your OP to include a hand-drawn example of what you would like to show.

Comment: @StuSmith Your considerations are correct. The research question belongs to a possible influence of lynx on deer behavior. For this I gained data of meadows in a detailed way. I recored when deer came on meadows, how long they were staying and how they behave. This data I collected in two different years. In the first year, no lynx were present. Then lynx were released in this area. After a few years I repeated my meadow camera trap study. Now I want to include the lynx presence. They are not the same locations. The lynx and the deer studies were conducted independently of each other.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out myself which tools I have to use:

First: I used the wrong heatmap tool. Not the heatmap configurator which can be find in the symbol layer of the shape, but the tool "interpolation - heatmap". Here is how it looks like: [image]
This heatmap tool generates raster data with values. In my case I used the the lynx-camera trap layer and weighted it with the lynx event attribute.

Second: I installed a plugin called "point sampling tool" which looks like this: [image]
With this tool I can choose my meadow-camera traps which contains my sampling points and the generated raster data of the lynx-camera traps where I want to get the values from for my sampling points. Running this tool generates a geo-package layer with the meadow sampling points and assigned values of the raster.